# How do i getting Rss feeds from different website to windows phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, rss, rss-reader

link to the example image [rss feeds from 1st4fans of Manchester United edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsnNm.png) 
I am kind a new in the c#  and would like to get feeds from different website to my windows phone app. 
My main interest is to get the image , heading and description to the feeds .
Link to the app is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/1st4fans-manchester-united-edition/9wzdncrdmkrp).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx) class.
Here is an example from one of my own apps:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String str = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.plasticsoldierreview.com/RSS/PlasticSoldierReview.xml"));

    SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed();
    feed.Load(str);

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
      // Extract the information from the SyndicationItem object ....
    }
```

Comment: How about adding different sources of the feed?